# Ethernet adapter broken after VMWare deinstallation

Tags: windows, networking, driver, ethernet

Unfortunately I cannot connect over LAN anymore after i deinstalled the VMWare Workstation Player.
The error just says "network cable unplugged". Which is obviously wrong.

What I've already did:

- Rebooting
- Updating the ethernet driver
- Removing the adapter with and without the driver
- Resetting all network settings

I'm pretty clueless at the moment.

[image: Cable unplugged]

Comment: Do you see a green and orange light burning/flashing on your motherboard connector?

Comment: I'm afraid not!

Comment: Could you try putting the cable into another machine to make sure it's working?

Comment: The cable is working. I also plugged the cable from a working machine into the faulty adapter. No go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the downvotes ;)

I fixed it by booting into linux. It somehow re-initiated the ethernet port.